# Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_query(): Argument #1 ($mysql) must be of type mysqli, string given

Tags: php

```
<html>
    <body>   
        <?php
            include ('conex.php');
        
            $link = Conectarse();
            $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
            $contra = $_POST['contra'];
            $saldo = $_POST['saldo'];
            $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
            $domicilio = $_POST['domicilio'];
            $telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
        
            mysqli_query("INSERT INTO usuarios(usuario,contra,prioridad,saldo,nombre,domicilio,telefono,email) values ('$usuario','$nombre','0','$saldo','$nombre','$domicilio','$telefono','$email')", $link);
        
            echo "<script>alert(\"DATOS CORRECTOS Y ALMACENADOS EN LA BASE DE DATOS...\"); </script>";
            echo "<script language= Javascript> location.href=\"centro.html\";</script>";
            die();
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

y este es el error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_query(): Argument #1 ($mysql) must be of
 type mysqli, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\negociojgtr\almausuario.php:14
Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\negociojgtr\almausuario.php(14):
 mysqli_query('INSERT INTO usu...', Object(mysqli)) #1 {main} thrown in
 C:\xampp\htdocs\negociojgtr\almausuario.php on line 14
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <body>   
        <?php
            include ('conex.php');
        
            $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
            $contra = $_POST['contra'];
            $saldo = $_POST['saldo'];
            $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
            $domicilio = $_POST['domicilio'];
            $telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
        
            $sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios(usuario,contra,prioridad,saldo,nombre,domicilio,telefono,email) VALUES ('$usuario','$nombre','0','$saldo','$nombre','$domicilio','$telefono','$email')";

            $resultado = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die ('Error: '. mysqli_error($con));

            header ('Location: centro.html');
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: te da error porque no pasas la $con = conexión